# Installing error

Tags: magento-1.9, mcrypt

I am using XAMPP with PHP 7.2.3

When I try to install Magento 1.9.2

It's giving the following error

> PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.
>
> PHP extension "soap" must be loaded.

Please, guide me how to install above extension.?

Comment: Please check our answer. Hope it'll help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

If your server does not have curl installed on it you can type one of the following commands to install it:

For Debian/Ubuntu based systems you can type below command

> sudo apt-get install php5-curl
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

For RedHat/CentOS based systems you can type (as root)

yum install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
This should install curl and have it start to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install both extensions before installing Magento on your server.

**Use following commands for install both extensions:**

> sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt    //For php5
>
> sudo apt-get install php7.2-mcrypt  //For php7
>
> sudo apt-get install php5-soap    //For php5
>
> sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap  //For php7
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what if he/she is using Windows :)

Comment: if windows then just enable it from the wampserver tray icon

Comment: How to do in windows? No option in the tray icon.